# MySQL, limit one table in join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table A and B. A has one column a_id. B has two columns b_id and a_id (a_id is foreign key here). A-B is 1-n relationship. Want to SELECT a_id of A with LIMIT, at the same time return all b_id that associated with those selected a_id. Without LIMIT it can be done by

```
SELECT A.a_id, B.b_id FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.a_id = B.a_id;
```

But how can I LIMIT only A without LIMIT the final result.

Comment: So you want to join B with only a limited set if Ries from A?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
 SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT A.a_id FROM A LIMIT 10) AS ALIMIT
   LEFT JOIN B ON ALIMIT.a_id = B.a_id;
```

Comment: The Inner query should only have "A.a_id" in the SELECT

Comment: Great! Glad to help!

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.